# Setup apache2 for routing internal requests

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have multiple **Django** applications, running on the same server under **apache2** **mod_wsgi**, each having its own domain and conf file.

```
etc/
├─ apache2/
│  ├─ sites-available/
│  │  ├─ 000-default.conf
│  │  ├─ a.example.com.conf
│  │  ├─ b.example.com.conf
```

These applications communicate with each other via http over the internet.
I would like to route these requests locally without going through the internet seeking for reduced latency.

My current setup is based on the typical **Django** **mod_wsgi** as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

```
...
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/path/to/venv python-path=/path/to/mysite.com
WSGIProcessGroup example.com
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=example.com
...
```

Any suggestion for a way to allow application **A** to reach application **B** via localhost call for internal requests ?

Comment: Will your applications respond correctly to traffic regardless the host name used? Or are they hard-coded to redirect traffic to the configured domains?

Comment: If I got what you said, they’re hardcodes to redirect traffic according to domain.